# Conditionally serialize collection field best practice?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I already have a solution to my problem, I'll describe it later, but I don't like it that's why I ask.

I'm using newest libraries of jersey and jackson. I have a rest service for an entity, so far, I have 2 get methods: getById and getList, both return json using jackson. The entity refers to itself using OneToMany relationship so it's a set of entities. For getList i don't want that field to be serialized and for getById I want it to be serialized but in my own way.

My solution is:

For getList I use view on a field
In entity bean I use my JsonView class FirstLevelOfCollection:

```
@JsonView(JacksonViews.FirstLevelOfCollection.class)
```

In rest service getList method, I use Object as a view filter so all all field without @JsonView will be included:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
resultString = mapper.writerWithView(Object.class).writeValueAsString(resultObject);
```

For getById I use custom serialize

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
testModule.addSerializer(Set.class, new EndEventCodesSerializer(Set.class));
mapper.registerModule(testModule);
resultString  = mapper.writeValueAsString(resultObject);
```

I can't use @JsonIgnore insted of view because then custom serialize will not see it too. It works but it seems weird and ugly especially to exclude field like that, what I also wanted to achieve but I don't know how is to use an exclusion(getList behavior) by default for all future request. Can I have a better solution?

Comment: Consider just using a transfer object. Trying to shove your DB jpa entities into JSON while may seem DRY ends up being a ton of work,confusing and potential security issues.

Comment: @Adam Gent You mean to put JsonIgnore on that Set field in the entity bean(for getList rest method) and write an entity wrapper with getter for that Set field(for getById rest method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I took Adam Gent advice.
I put @JsonIgnore on all reference fields, implemented several DTO's which are just wrappers of my entity classes, and I response in rest services with these DTO's.